# Double-ended arrow with a dot after. Notation Question

Tags: logic, notation

Good afternoon.

I have a quick question. What is the meaning of ↔. ?
(as opposed to purely ↔). The context arises in some basic set definitions (below). The first has no 'dot' whereas the 2nd and 3rd do:-

∀x ( x ∈ {a} ↔ x=a )

∀x ( x ∈ {a,b} ↔. x=a ∨ x=b )

∀x ( x ∈ {a,b,c} ↔. x=a ∨ x=b ∨ x=c )

I know that the ↔ by itself means 'if and only if'  and I imagine the addition of the dot still means something similar, but I can't find out what.

Thanks for your help.

Drex

Comment: Just guessing. Perhaps it's some sort of preference sign? (From the point to the next closing parenthesis or the end). That is: $A\leftrightarrow.B\wedge C$ is the same as $A\leftrightarrow(B\wedge C)$

Comment: Thanks. I was worried it was something more specific!  don't understand the down vote thing? My first post. Don't even know how to vote!

Comment: Be careful! I was only guessing!

Comment: I believe you are correct. Using this information I found another post on this site:- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311871/what-are-the-rules-for-the-use-of-dots-rather-than-parentheses-in-logical-formul

Comment: It is only a parentheses. The second one is $∀x ( x ∈ \{ a,b \} ↔ (x=a ∨ x=b) )$. The "dot notation" was due to Peano and used in logic into W&R's [Principia Mathematica](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/#UseDotsForPunc).

Answer (score 1):

This sort of use of the dot as punctuation can be just thought of as marking a pause, so that

∀x ( x ∈ {a,b} ↔. x=a ∨ x=b )

is in effect

∀x ( x ∈ {a,b} ↔ [*wait for it ...!*]  x=a ∨ x=b )

so naturally gathering what follows into a unit. Hence it is a bracketing device. (And "↔." is no more a unit with its own significance than is, say, "↔ ("

The once-common use of dots for bracketing duty seems to have its origins in  *Principia Mathematica*. I'd forgotten I'd written that answer on official dotty conventions at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/312074, so thanks for the link that saves me writing something similar! :) But as I say, in relaxed contexts like the present example, you needn't worry about official conventions. Just think of it as like a pause to break up a sentence and group it. As we do in ordinary language. Thus compare the familiar example of the party invitation ...

> Bring your partner or come alone [pause] and have a good time
>
> Bring your partner [pause] or come alone and have a good time

Without the spoken pause, or the written comma, it would be ambiguous. Likewise without the dot, or bracketing, or an operator-precedence-convention,

∀x ( x ∈ {a,b} ↔ x=a ∨ x=b )

would be potentially ambiguous (even though one reading is daft).

Comment: I assumed the quoted material was from a regular maths book, written in that usual semi-formal way where you notationally use what works without worrying *too* much about formal punctiliousness. But yes ok "informal" wasn't the mot juste, and I've deleted it!